# JPA support for outer joins without object relational mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, outer-join

Recently i had to use an outer join between two JPA entities that doesnt have object relational mapping. Going by the spec and the forum posts, outer joins are supported only if the entities are mapped at JPA level.

Example code below. Requirement is to find customers without any orders.

```
@Entity
class Customer {
    private int id;
}
@Entity
class Order {
    private int customerId;
    public int getCustomerId() { return customerId; }
    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) { this.customerId = customerId ; }
}
```

In my case, i had to opt for the native queries to get the job done.

Any thoughts on if future JPA specs going to support outer joins without relational mapping ?

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: Sorry, can you explain your question a bit more? Did you define the Entity classes but not the association between them? Can you post the code of what you tried? And maybe tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thats right, JPA entities without any relation defined at JPA level. Edited to include example code. In the given scenario, JPA does not offer outer join. Reason:  it needs object path as per the 2/2.1 spec.

Comment: So why not define the Entities 'properly' with the associations and make your life easier? What disadvantage is there (apart from you having to type a bit more code) to defining the relationship between these Entities?

Comment: @DuncanKinnear thats a good question. Defining JPA level OR mappings is largely situation dependent. They are a life saver when it comes to situation where one entity is 'composed in' another entity i.e. entity1 exists only when entity2 exists. However, its not a must in ALL situations. For ex. auditing is one such example. I would rather avoid OR mapping itself rather than have mapping and then deal with lazy/eager loading and the associated hibernate session boundaries issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `customerId` field (`Integer`) in the `Order` entity. In order to find customers without any orders, you can avoid outer join and native query by using subquery:

```
select c from Customer c where id not in (select customerId from Order)
```

This way you achieve the same goal in JPQL (HQL).

Comment: Hmmm, typically we dont add columns just to support query. In the reported case, Customer already has orderId, Having customerId in Order is redundant and is not the correct approach.

Comment: upvoting as it does work provided the asosciation is defined as suggested

Comment: Accepting as answer as it gets what is required. However, i would still opt for native query with left outer join to avoid inner query. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a theta-style join to emulate an INNER JOIN:

```
    select c, o
    from Customer c, Order o
    where c.id= o.customerId
```

Most modern database engine query optimizers will turn it into an [INNER JOIN equivalent anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause).

Comment: Thanks. Logically that should work. Will test and revert back.

Comment: i just modified the entity definitionas in the OP. Can you please suggest modifications in the query you mentioned for LEFT JOIN ? Thanks.

Comment: the query is returning all i.e. customers with orders as well as without orders. But what is needed is customers WITHOUT orders.

Comment: That's how LEFT join works. Try Dragan answer for Customers without Orders.